issues with aligning text for pytesseract ocr

image 1

image 2
for some reason why I try to use pytesseract on image 1, i wontt get any output but the image 2 gives me output. the original image is skewed image which i preprocessed with pyteseeract image_to_osd and deskew library as suggested in this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801250/16388623). the image 2 is the one i cropped manually with images app on windows and pytesseract seems to work on that but not image 1 im not sure why.
I have attached the original image too. help me out to figure what am I doing wrong here

I am expecting th output about characters from given image.

it's mostly due to the white lines at the top, I tried the same image after cropping and it worked. not really helpful to solve the problem but it would solve my use case so no worries
